# How to show List of Checkbox item value in JSP Page

Tags: sql-server, spring-mvc, jsp

I am not able to show checkbox value in JSP page and it shows some random data.

after saving,  some random value is also stored in database and it is not able to store all 3 values in one column (stud_language column) in DB and i took datatype as varchar(100) for stud_language column

My Jsp Code.

Student.jsp

```
<td><form:label path = "stud_language">Language Known</form:label></td>
               <td><form:checkboxes items = "${stud_language}" path = "stud_language" /></td>
```

Controller.java

```
 @ModelAttribute("stud_language")
       public Map<String, String> getStudLanguage() {
          Map<String, String> stud_language = new HashMap<String, String>();
          stud_language.put("Hindi", "Hindi");
          stud_language.put("Marathi", "Marathi");
          stud_language.put("English", "English"); 
          return stud_language;
```

Student_List.jsp (where i want to shown the output where some random values are coming instead of checkbox items value)

```
 <c:forEach items="${students}" var="stud">       
            <td>${stud.stud_language}</td>
```

i tried with this above code using for each but it show the same random  value instead of Checkbox value as English,Hindi,Marathi both in view page and Database one column. How should i display all 3 checkbox values in one field and also how can i store all 3 checkbox values in one column in DB?

Comment: Please don't post data as an image, the volunteers here will really struggle to use it, if at all. We can't copy and paste it, interact with it, or much else; you're therefore expecting the users here to re-type all your data. Please provide the data as `text`. Thank you.

Comment: You should not store your data like that. It's just going to cause problems for you when you need to search things. You're also violating the [First normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) of database design

Comment: Edited, tried many ways but still same random values is coming instead of checkbox values.